# Groovy:Apparent variable xyz was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-tool-suite

I am getting this "error" in an Spring Tool Suite for all of my domain classes.  Its not really an error, because it compiles fine.  But it's masking real compile errors, how can I get rid of it ?   They are in the same package, so I dont need the import, if I add the import it says it can't find the class...

So the following code produce a red x

> Groovy:Apparent variable 'ExampleB' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static 
>    field or class. Possible causes:

```
package domain.com.so;

class ExampleA {
    static belongsTo  = [exampleB: ExampleB]
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

---

And this code produces a simpilar error:

> Groovy:Apparent variable 'ExampleA' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field 
>    or class. Possible causes:

```
package domain.com.so;

class ExampleB {
    static hasMany  = [exampleAs: ExampleA]
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Comment: simply ignore it if it works.. Spring Tool Suite  is not perfect :)

Comment: Ignoring it causes my project to be bloody all the time, and us `OCD` folks can't handle that.

Comment: Intellij IDEA. Also `grails clean`.

Comment: Normally when STS complains something like this I `clean` and `compile --refresh-dependencies` the project.

Comment: @SérgioMichels I did what you said, and it actually cleared out my error.  Please post as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally when STS complains something like this I run

```
grails clean
```

and

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had this problem with ggts 3.6.3. I tried a variety of things but this ended up being the solution for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

This happens quite often when I'm making changes to static members and the dynamic reloading is enabled while running the application.  I find I have to delete and re-add the project to the workspace.  It's almost like the metadata for the project gets in a "stuck" state of when the error occurred during run-time.